# Is there a CLI utility to compute the same CRC as used in ZIP files?

Tags: zip, checksum

```bash
# Create random file    
$ dd if=/dev/urandom /of=./test.dat bs=1K count=1

# Zip it 
$ zip test.zip test.dat

# Dump contents for ZIP-computed CRC
$ unzip -v test.zip
Archive:  test.zip
Length   Method    Size  Cmpr    Date    Time   CRC-32   Name
--------  ------  ------- ---- ---------- ----- --------  ----
    1024  Stored     1024   0% 2018-12-09 17:42 1f197320  test.dat
--------          -------  ---                            -------
    1024             1024   0%                            1 file

# compute CRC with coreutil's cksum
$ cksum test.dat
283837118 1024 test.dat

# convert to hex
$ printf "%08x" 283837118
10eb02be
```

TL;DR: `cksum` doesn't use the same CRC algorithm as ZIP.

Comment: According to the `cksum` info page (`info '(coreutils) cksum invocation'`), "the algorithm is specified by POSIX".  Or according to https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/cksum-invocation.html, there's now a `--algorithm` option with `crc` as the default for `cksum`.  So it's a CRC with some polynomial.  https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/cksum.html specifies the polynomial, and that it's the Ethernet standard CRC, i.e. CRC32C used by modern things like btrfs and the x86 `crc` insn, not the traditional CRC32 polynomial used by many older things like ZIP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `crc32` command which is available in the `Archive::Zip` Perl module. On Debian and derivatives, install [`libarchive-zip-perl`](https://packages.debian.org/all/libarchive-zip-perl/filelist) to get it.

Comment: I want to add a warning about undocumented behavior of the `crc32` command. If the filename contains something that looks like a CRC32, it will compare it to the computed CRC and add a message to the stdout about whether it matches! I wonder how many scripts this has messed up? Btw, guess what looks like a CRC32? A date in the format `20200630`!